# fastest regex to split string containing code into individual key value pairs of var's and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string of some javascript code,

```
"var obj1 = { width : 120;height    : 80;length : 0;};var obj2 = {width : 80;height     : 10;length : 30;};"
```

I'd like to spit it into an object with key value pairs  like

```
{
  "obj1": "width   : 120;height  : 80;length  : 0;",
  "obj2": "width : 80;height  : 10;"

}
```

Would `/^(\"[^"]*\"|.*?)=(\"[^"]*\"|.*?)$/` be the fastest way to find them?

Comment: Why do you have this return in the first place? Couldn't you use JSON instead?

Comment: The fastest way would be to use `JSON.parse()`, but to use that, you need to change invalid syntax to valid one, i.e. change semicolons to commas.

Comment: If you're just looking for performance improvements, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate.

Comment: "If your values can be any string, you're gonna have a bad time" ~ Noam Chomsky

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many questions on SO that users asks for Regex to fulfill there NEEDS when RegEx is an overkill from performance perspective.

A short answer to your question:

> 1) RegEx is something that is not designed to parse a JSON response. (Don't use it)
>
> 2) Use JSON Parser to mold your response as per your need. (If you want good performance)

But if you still think that you are bound to use RegEx (for some reason) or parsing a JSON will lead you to do some more additional work than you have to do with RegEx.

You can go with this RegEx:

```
(\w+)\s(?:\=\s{)([\w\s\:;]+)(?=})
```

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/4o5D2fkYxb) each match will have exactly two groups:

Do the following:

> 1) Wrap `each group` in a `match` with `"` (Double-quote)
>
> 2) Join `groups` with `:`
>
> 3) Wrap `matches` with `{` and `}`.

Hope it helps!